# starting pgbouncer on startup

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgbouncer

I installed pgbouncer and configured it and it starts only via using this command

```
pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
```

however using service pgbouncer start it dose not start. I then set up supervior with this settings to mannage it which works fine.

```
[program:pgbouncer]
command=pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/pg_bouncer.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/pg_bouncer_error.log
autostart=true
stopsignal=QUIT
redirect_stderr=true
directory=/etc/pgbouncer/
user=postgres
group=postgres
preload_app = True
```

when i reboot the system pgbouncer dose not work,looking into the pgbouncer log here is what the error says

```
WARNING Cannot listen on ::/6432: bind(): Address already in use
WARNING Cannot listen on unix:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.6432: bind(): No such file or directory
FATAL @src/main.c:553 in function write_pidfile(): /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid: No such file
```

and looking into supervisor log this is what it says

```
LOG File descriptor limit: 1024 (H:4096), max_client_conn: 100, max fds possible: 130
LOG listening on 0.0.0.0:6432
WARNING Cannot listen on ::/6432: bind(): Address already in use
WARNING Cannot listen on unix:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.6432: bind(): No such file or directory
FATAL @src/main.c:553 in function write_pidfile(): /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid: No such file or directory
```

can any one help out with this please

Comment: maybe too little too late, but I found this helpful http://blog.tomnod.com/install-pgbouncer-ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I was putting my pidfile in /var/run which is fine for running it but when server is rebooted the file is deleted and pgbouncer can't find the file and it gives the this error

```
FATAL @src/main.c:553 in function write_pidfile(): /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid: No such file or directory
```

So simply moving the file to another location and chown the directory was all that was needed

```
$ sudo mkdir ~/pgbouncer
$ sudo chown -R postgres:postgres ~/pgbouncer
```

Answer (score 0):

If your port is taken you can always check what's occupying your port

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 6432
```

In my case I had pboucner already running, found this with

```
pgrep pbouncer
```